# foreach loop is only getting the first value when i upload multiple images and loop throw them

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a Multi-image upload system and when I started uploading images and return the $image var it only shows me the first input.

I already looked at the StackOverflow Questions and found nothing that can help me

```
// get the images from the input file 
$images = $request->file('g_images_thumbnails');
// loop throw the result
foreach ($images as $image) {
// return the image value
return $image;
}
```

```
// this to open the form
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'AdminBrowsergamesController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}
// this is the image upload input field
{!! Form::file('g_images_thumbnails[]',['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple', 'accept' => 'image/*']) !!} 
// this is the submit button
{!! Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'form-control btn btn-info w-50']) !!} 
// this is the close form
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

it should loop throw all result and show them but it only shows the first result.

Comment: Calling `dd()` inside the loop may be something to do with it.

Comment: Whats the output of `$images` ?

Comment: `dd` is __dump and DIE__ So your script dies on first iteration. You should know the tools you work with.

Comment: I know the tools am working with and dump and die I want it to dump the array values and die before reaching the upload process and it choose the same when i use the return function only getting the first value

Comment: choose = shows from the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try with following code

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {

        $this->validate($request, [

                'filename' => 'required',
                'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'

        ]);

        if($request->hasfile('g_images_thumbnails'))
         {

            foreach($request->file('g_images_thumbnails') as $image)
            {
                $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
                $data[] = $name;  
            }
         }

         $form= new Form();
         $form->filename=json_encode($data);


        $form->save();

        return back()->with('success', 'Your images has been successfully');
    }
```

A complete tutorial about Laravel Multiple files upload can be found here https://appdividend.com/2018/02/05/laravel-multiple-images-upload-tutorial/